# Android Emulator communication from different machines

Tags: android, android-emulator, ip-address

I've referred the developer site and have implemented the following idea that works fine for two emulator instances running on same machine.

•A is you development machine
•B is your first emulator instance, running on A
•C is your second emulator instance, also running on A

and you want to run a server on B, to which C will connect, here is how you could set it up: 
1.Set up the server on B, listening to 10.0.2.15:
2.On B's console, set up a redirection from A:localhost: to B:10.0.2.15:
3.On C, have the client connect to 10.0.2.2:

For example, if you wanted to run an HTTP server, you can select  as 80 and  as 8080:
•B listens on 10.0.2.15:80
•On B's console, issue redir add tcp:8080:80
•C connects to 10.0.2.2:8080

Now for two diffenrent machines I have to make C connect to A's ipaddress:8080. This doesn't work though. What Address should be given in place of 10.0.2.2 for this to work? The IPAddress alone is apparently not sufficient.
I've been stuck with this for abt a week. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If i just use the Ipaddress of the server(with 8080 port) from the client, i get java.net.conectExcperion:Connection Rfused : Connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. you need server between two emulator. it's not possible to connect two emulator without any intermediate. This role perform by [Google App engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine)``.
Google App Engine is complete, scalable and affordable hosting solution. [Using Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/),you can do this.   [Check this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/06/android-app-engine-integration.html).

**App Engine With XMPP:**

With the introduction of the XMPP service to App Engine, it's  possible to write an App Engine app that communicates with users - or even other applications - over XMPP. XMPP is an instant-messaging protocol, used by Google Talk, Jabber, and other IM networks.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp) one good tutorial of XMPP.
[One Example of App Engine.](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_create_project).
Hope this will help you.

**Update:**

`java.net.conectExcperion:Connection Rfused : Connect android`

This exception occurs when  no service listening on the port you are trying to connect.

You also need to understand [Emulator Networking](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#emulatornetworking)

Comment: It's too bad that we need an intermediate...can't google come up with an API that overcomes this...And i've implemented an intermediate java prgm to route the traffic. Thanks for ur ans  :)

Comment: if i find something regarding this. i'll post it.

Comment: I'd appreciate if u could please loot at this too  [A similar q.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520437/android-tcp-communication-over-the-internetnot-lan).