# Android TCP communication over the internet(not LAN).

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, android-emulator, router

I'm creating an app to establish communication between two android `mobiles` through the internet using TCP sockets. So, I'll primarily be using ip addresses of the two `mobiles` with my fancy app port no.

**Is this possible? To create custom TCP ports and communicate over the internet like in a LAN?**

So far i'm able to successfully communicate between two emulators in a LAN . But it's not possible to do the same thorugh the internet in case of emultors cos usually the host machine is `behind a router` that allows only data to the port `8080` or `80` i'm not sure. Of course there are port forwarding that can be done, but i don't wanna get dirty with that.
so,
**Does emulator connection in LAN guarantee `mobile` connection in the internet?** cos in case of `mobile with direct net connectivity` there is only single ip address(no private and external ip) and no router to bar the trafffic.

Comment: That depends on how particular provider assigns addresses to the devices. I doubt they give you globally routable addresses, probably something in the private subnets like `192.168/16` or `10/8`, unless of course the provider goes all the way to IPv6.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov What's the advantage of ipv6 here?

Comment: 128-bit address instead of 32-bit one, so *much* more address space, thus no need for NAT games.

Answer (score 2):

Have You heard about hole punching technique. Read about this - maybe it will be helpfull.[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) This is how skype works I think.The technique requires yet another node in communication - a server which is accessible by both clients, and which helps to make direct connections between two clients even if one of the client is behind a NAT.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99.8% sure that you will not be able to do this on mobile networks. If I recall correctly, each cell tower has its own IP, and each device connected to it has a private, internal IP. However, I'm sure you could get this to work on Wifi.

Comment: Wow seroiusly?! So if i have two mobiles using same metwork provider in a same area connected to the internet, they'll have the same external ip?